# How to get video from web socket url in android?

Tags: android, websocket, mp4, android-videoview, exoplayer

I want to get a video mp4 file from web socket URL in android, 
The URL look like the following example:

> "ws://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com/mp4

I have no idea if its possible in exoplayer , and if so then how is it possible in a web socket url (Not Http).

I would be happy to receive any example to this problem

Comment: hey Moti, have you found any solution ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at okhttp from 3.5.0 they support websockets. Then you can OkHttpDataSource with ExoPlayer.

Comment: OkHttpDataSource of ExoPlayer supports only http how can i use web sockets??

Comment: @rajahsekar, I'm very sorry that my answer was so short, perhaps it is wrong, we'll have to wait for Moti's response.
I believe in order to implement `DataSource` around the websocket in easiest fashion you'll have to send request to server when asked to `read` and block until answer is received.